Could Sized bounds be inferred?
Generic type parameters are implicitly Sized, because that is usually what you want, but if you don't need it, you have to explicitly opt out (via : ?Sized). Would it be possible (and make sense) for the compiler to automatically determine whether a given generic type must be Sized or not, without requiring manual annotation?
// T is arg so Sized, also T is ret-val so Sized
fn fn_with_sized_type<T>(x: T) -> T { ... } 

// T is always behind a &, so need not be Sized
fn fn_with_unsized_type<T>(x: &T) -> &T { ... } 


Try asking over on the Rust internals forum: https://internals.rust-lang.org/

Rust doesn't inspect the body of functions to determine (very rarely anyways) if the signature is valid, this is done on purpose. Generally you might think you want implicit trait bounds, lifetime bounds, etc but they almost always prove a footgun sooner rather than later. This is true for the exception Rust makes so some people consider these mistakes as well. Without inspecting the body this is not possible in general as orlps answer shows.

Just because something is behind a reference does not mean it's always allowed to be unsized, consider the following:
pub fn swap<T>(x: &mut T, y: &mut T)

You can't implement this function for unsized types, so the inferring mechanic would have to inspect to see if you are doing operations that require Sized to the element behind the reference. And this would violate a guiding principle in Rust, that the function signature does not depend on the body of the function.

The way I read OP's thought was the default (T: Sized or T: ?Sized) would be inferred from the signature but could obviously be overridden with T: Sized if needed.

@kmdreko OP asked if it was possible (emphasis mine) "to automatically determine whether a given generic type must be Sized or not". That depends on the body of the function.

Thanks, that's useful. However there is precedent for delaying some type checks to instantiation (trait Works {fn foo() -> Self;}). Alternatively perhaps you could view such faulty instantiation not as a type error, but as akin to a borrow error; not part of the function signature. Then perhaps it would be fine to inspect the body?
